# Bash script - How is 6 > 50?

Tags: bash, shell-script, arithmetic

```
if [[ 6 > 50 ]]; then
    echo "true"
fi
```

`$ bash script.sh`

I'm missing something very obvious here. Why is 6 greater than 50 ??

** EDIT **

I'm also try to solve for

```
if [[ 6.5 > 50 ]]; then
    echo "true"
fi
```

Comment: From `man bash`: *"When used with [[, the < and > operators sort lexicographically using the current locale."*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to compare floats, the easiest way is to call out to an external tool like awk or bc

```bsh
a=6.1
b=50
if [[ "$(echo "$a > $b" | bc)" -eq 1 ]]; then echo "a greater than b"; fi
```

Comment: I'm not as familiar with bash scripting (obviously) so I appreciate you answering my "silly" question with a formative and informational answer rather than exercising contempt on me for knowing less than you in this given situation. Cheers @glennJackman

Comment: No worries. There are no silly questions, providing you [follow a few sensible guidelines](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 3):

If you're comparing integers then use

`if [[ 6 -gt 50 ]]; then echo "true"; fi`

otherwise since bash cannot handle floating point

`if (( $(echo "6.5 > 50" | bc -l) )); then echo "true"; fi`

Answer (score 2):

You supplied `[[ args ]]` which is a **[conditional expression](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/bash.1.html#conditional%20expressions)**, when you meant to perform **[arithmetic evaluation](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/bash.1.html#arithmetic%20evaluation)** which uses the `(( condition ))` syntax.

Comment: In certain situations I have a float in there and when I've tried this I get `syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".00 > 50 ")`

Comment: @Jacksonkr Bash does not do floats.  A good starting point for questions like these is to consult `man bash`.

Comment: @John1024 What about [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23533477/332578)